Bear with an airship
I remember a cartoon from when I was younger (late 80s early 90s) with a bear who had an airship. The ship was like a pirate ship with a quilted balloon on the top. I believe the enemy was some sort of a lizard wizard type thing.
I remember I had the toys but alas they are gone and my parents do not remember the name. Any ideas here?

Thanks to everyone that answered this. I haven been trying to figure this out for years. I had no idea that Teddy Ruxpin had a show. Time to watch it again.

The Adventures of Teddy Ruxpin

The Adventures of Teddy Ruxpin follows young Teddy Ruxpin as he leaves
  his home on the island of Rillonia with his best friend Grubby to
  follow an ancient map which leads him to find a collection of crystals
  on the mainland of Grundo. With the help of his new friend Newton
  Gimmick, Teddy and Grubby discover the magical powers of what turns
  out to be an ancestral treasure as well as an organization with
  ambitions to use it for evil known as M.A.V.O. (short for Monsters and
  Villains Organization). Along the way, Teddy learns the long-lost
  history of his species and clues to the location of his missing
  father.

The ship:

The bear:

The opening:


 

I believe you are thinking about The Adventures of Teddy Ruxpin.
The Adventures of Teddy Ruxpin




You may be thinking about Teddy Ruxpin.  Or more accurately, the television series The Adventures of Teddy Ruxpin.
